# Why does my rails app ignore the env var DATABASE_URL at console startup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**tl;dr:**

```
$ export DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:pwd@localhost:5432/new_db
$ RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails c
[1] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
=> "test"
[2] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection;nil
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
=> "new_db"
[4] pry(main)> # WTF ?!?
```

**Background**: We are currently hosting several jobs to build, test and push to heroku our DEV and QA environments. As we were having the same test configuration in the database.yml file, we ended up with failing tests when both env where tested at the same time, so we decided to use two databases.

**What we were trying**: To achieved that (use several databases whith the same database.yml file), we decided to set to value of the DATABASE_URL environment variable to 'postgres://user:pwd@localhost:5432/new_db'.

**What is the issue**: The value of DATABASE_URL only seems to be used when we run establish_connection manually in a console. Oddly, running rake has effect on the right db (new_db).

Rails version is 3.2.19

Is there any way to override properly that environment variable ?

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a file in config/initializers that did this:

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
    config['pool']              = ENV['DB_POOL'] || 5
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

This file says: Always load the configuration from database.yml, and add the two parameters `reaing_frequency` and `pool`.

Changing the initializer to this solves the problem:

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    if !ENV['DATABASE_URL']
      config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
      config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
      config['pool'] = ENV['DB_POOL'] || 5
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
    else
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    end
  end
end
```

Note: The default rails behaviour is to search the config first in `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` then in `config/database.yml`. So if you just remove the initializer, that also solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you still encounter this problem with Rails 4.2, please try to stop spring with `spring stop` first. Spring will accept the new ENV variable when it starts again.

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced similar issue with Rails 4.2. In addition to @mario-uher comment on stopping spring there is one more thing to keep in mind. I've been accessing database configuration in my initializer like this:

```ruby
Rails.application.configure do |app|
  app.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
end
```

Doing so will return settings from **database.yml** **only**. Actual merging magic occurs in ActiveRecord itself. So merged config should be accessed like this:

```ruby
ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]
```